# Django - update custom context in view

Tags: django

I have a custom context processor that passes some server side constants to the client (by injecting into javascript object). Some views might want to add additional params, notifications for example, to the dict.

```
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site

def client_context(request):
    params = {}

    domain = get_current_site(request).domain
    schema = request.scheme
    params['rooturl'] = "%s://%s" % (schema,domain)

    return {'params': params}
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/)

> **When context processors are applied**
>
> Context processors are applied after the context itself is processed. This means that a context processor may overwrite variables you’ve supplied to your Context or
>   RequestContext, so take care to avoid variable names that overlap with
>   those supplied by your context processors.

If I render a template without overriding `params` it's working fine - i get the baseurl in the template.

If I render the template with a variable named `params` i get only the overrided value.

```
def home(request):  
    return render(request, 'home.html', { 'params' : {'page' : 'home'} })
```

so i have two questions

1. Is the django docs incorrect ? from what i understand the second
   dict should `update` the first one. According to these findings my
   custom context is applied first.
2. What is the best way to achieve this ?

**EDIT**

In my `base.html` file (extended by all other templates) i pass the `params` object to a Js objects. e.g

```
{% block init %}
<script>
   Global = new Global( {{ params | json }} );
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

I was hoping for a solution that wont require adding each possible parameter by name

```
{% block init %}
<script>
   Global = new Global( { baseurl : "{{baseurl}}", page : "{{ page }}" );
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django is working as documented. The `params` returned by your template context processor is overwriting the `params` in the view's context. Django doesn't automatically merge dictionaries as you want.

Instead of using the `render` shortcut, you could make your views return [`TemplateResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/template-response/#templateresponse-objects) objects. Then, instead of writing a context processor, write a middleware that updates the `params` dict in the [`process_template_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/middleware/#process_template_response) method.

Comment: A middleware sounds like a good idea - I'm using `render` because it saves me the trouble of passing the context on each execution - what is the difference between `render` and the `TemplateResponse` ?

Comment: `TemplateResponse` takes the same arguments as the render shortcut, but it allows you to use the `process_template_response` middleware method to update the context before the template is rendered. Like `render`, it uses a `RequestContext`.